# How configure the upstart in ubuntu in my ec2 [node.js]

Tags: upstart, amazon-ec2, amazon

I am using an amazon ec2 instance with ubuntu to host my node.js application, i already made all the configurations, and is working good when i type:

```
nodemon ./bin/www
```

./bin/www is the file that creates the server.

Now, i am trying to setup the upstart, and i follow a tutorial, this is my configuration file:

path:

```
/etc/init/photogrid.conf:
```

inside:

```
description "Photogrid"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env NODE_ENV=production

exec node /home/ubuntu/photogrid/bin/www >> /var/log/photogrid.log 2>&1
```

But when i try to access the site, is showing:

```
Cannot GET /
```

I follow a tutorial, and the only difference between my configuration file is this part:

Original:

```
exec node /home/ubuntu/photogrid/app.js >> /var/log/photogrid.log 2>&1
```

My one:

```
exec node /home/ubuntu/photogrid/bin/www >> /var/log/photogrid.log 2>&1
```

Start with upstart:

[image]

Start with nodemon bin/www:

[image]

In my logs i see the following when i try access the '/' (just an example, in every route is the same problem):

```
^[[0mGET / ^[[33m404 ^[[0m12.036 ms - 13^[[0m
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be problem with the working directory. Try using [`chdir`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#chdir):

```
description "Photogrid"

...

chdir /home/ubuntu/photogrid

exec node /home/ubuntu/photogrid/bin/www
```

On a side note: The redirection isn't needed. The log is saved to files in `/var/log/upstart/`.

Comment: let my try this

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH MURU!!!!! can you explain me the chdir?

Comment: @FátimaAlves When you run `node bin/www` you're always in the `/home/ubuntu/photogrid` directory. The server might be accessing files using relative paths `files/foo.html`, and those paths won't work if your working directory is elsewhere.